# How to update jquery datatable info to update the number of shown rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

My issue is that I want to update information part to show the real number of shown rows.
Suppose that I have 40 rows but I use radio filters. Each one when clicked make the datable be filtered.
Now, If the datatable is showing 4 rows among 40 then the information part must show a message like :

```
Showing elements 1 to 4 among 40
```

Here how make it :

```
updateTableShownRowsNumber=function(){
    var oTT = $('#table_id').dataTable();
    oTT.fnSetDisplayLength = 20;
    oTT.fnDraw();
};
```

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle? and I think `redraw` is not necessary unless you get the filtered data again from `serverside`!

Comment: I get the data stored in request and show it using the datatable. To avoid calling again another web service, I filter the line using a bean attribute value.I'm sorry but I can't provide a fiddle.

Comment: so basically `session` is a `serverside` concept! I hope you aren't clientside `sessionStorage`?

Comment: I'm sorry but I corrected my comment. I have a jsp file. I take the rows from request scope and then show them. So I guess it's a server side.